# Vimperator/Conkeror-like link selection

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, conkeror

I use Conkeror on a daily basis except at work where I need Firebug, since I'm a web developer. I really miss having the "follow link" ability in Conkeror but I don't want to resort to using Vimperator to get it.

Is there any Firefox extension which lets me follow links by hitting a key followed by the link text like in Conkeror?

Comment: This is the browser in question. Conkeror is not Konqueror. http://conkeror.org/

Comment: Sorry, I had completely forgoten about it as I have never used it :S I stand corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways you can already [use only the keyboard to browse with Firefox](http://lifehacker.com/139495/hack-attack-mouse+less-firefox).

> ### Searching pages
>
> The find-as-you-type feature was an epiphany. While Google is great at getting you to the right web page, Firefox's find-as-you-type feature gets you the rest of the way.
>
> - Find as you type text: /
> - Find as you type link: '
> - Regular old find: Ctrl/Cmd+F
>
> The link search is very useful, especially when used in conjunction with...
>
> ### Opening pages
>
> Unless you do all of your browsing in one page, these shortcuts are huge when you don't want to go running for your mouse.
>
> - Open link in new window: Shift+Enter
> - Open link in new tab: Ctrl/Cmd+Enter
> - Open address/search in new tab: Alt/Option+Enter
>
> Used together with their respective shortcuts (address and search bar shortcuts and the find-as-you-type link shortcut), the page opening shortcuts go a long way toward mouse-less browsing.

Of course, you can also use the [Mousless Browsing](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/879) plugin.

> Mouseless Browsing (MLB) enables you to browse the web entirely with the keyboard. The basic principle is to add small boxes with unique ids behind every link and/or form element. You just have to type in the id to trigger the corresponding action i.e. following a link, pressing a button or selecting a textfield...

Comment: Thank you for the pointer to Mouseless Browsing.  The Customizable Shortcuts firefox browser is also useful, but it has a big limitation: you can't combine keys as in conkeror, and I couldn't find a way to make (say) hjkl move around the text when I'm reading yet insert themselves in a text field.

Answer (score 2):

There's [Pentadactyl](http://dactyl.sourceforge.net/pentadactyl) - and all firefox extensions work well with it.

Answer (score 1):

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8781

Works even better with Linkification, I might add.